# Spring Boot - javax Import statements not working correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I just started working with ***Spring Boot***, and am currently following [this tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) with some small modifications to naming and using their own version of **`Eclipse`**, which has [this generator](http://start.spring.io/) built in.

When I get to the first snippet of code, I try just copying over the *import* statements to start with,

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
```

which gets me the following error with the javax imports:

```
The import javax.persistence.[insert name here] cannot be resolved
```

When I find the **`javax.persistence`** package, I find that, sure enough, the starter code provided from their own service does not contain the listed packages. I'm left confused and wondering if I did something wrong in the initial steps. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit 1: pom content provided

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.Me</groupId>
<artifactId>petstore</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>petstore</name>
<description>Petstore Project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: pom content please

Comment: @AmanTuladhar Pom content added

Comment: have you downloaded the jar dependencies via maven?

Comment: Have you added the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add  **`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`** dependency

If you are using **`Maven`** add to **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you are using **`Gradle`** add in **build.gradle**

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
```

for other refer [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa).

Comment: That seems to have worked, thank you. Odd that it didn't include that dependency at the start.

Comment: What about dependency version?

Comment: @carduque too late to reply but you need to add it dependency like this : implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-gradle-plugin', version: '6.0.0.Alpha6', ext: 'pom'

Comment: @carduque the version is already defined via dependencyManagement in the parent pom defined at the top:  spring-boot-starter-parent.  This is the "spring boot way": the concrete version that is compatible is defined for you.  You just add the dependency artifact without version.  That way you don't accidentally override the 'good' version and cause incompatibilities.

Comment: The gradle method `compile` is now replaced by `implementation`. So do  `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'`
instead.

Answer (score 53):

Perhaps this will help someone: apparently Javax persistence api is renamed to Jakarta persistence. So you will have to import `jakarta.persistence` instead of `javax.persistence`.

Comment: This was it for me

Comment: I was searching for javax.  Now got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Please refer the docs.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes

> As of #19550, Web and WebFlux starters do not depend on the validation starter by default anymore. If your application is using validation features, for example you find that javax.validation.* imports are not being resolved, you’ll need to add the starter yourself.
>
> For Maven builds, you can do that with the following:
>
> ```
>  <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> For Gradle, you will need to add something like this:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>   ...
>   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but previous solutions didn't work for me. I do solve the issue by adding following dependency to POM file.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency in you pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

After that Right click on your project and in maven option update your project. That should fix it.

Comment: Thank you CPT Kitkat. I was missing the reload...

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have added below spring boot data dependency  but still not be able to import `javax.persistence.*`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I realized that eclipse somehow not be able to adding this dependencies to my classpath. Firstly i tried right click on the project `Maven>Update Project`but still not worked. Then I execute `mvn eclipse:eclipse` inside the root directory and then after successful build i refreshed project in the eclipse. This time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solution steps:

1. open terminal
2. Go to root directory with "**cd**" command
3. list invisible folders with "**ls -a**"
4. you should see the .m2 file. There are all the maven repository on the .m2 file
5. Delete maven with command “**sudo rm -r .m2**”
6. Run the project again

Answer (score 0):

You can first import

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and use

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
```

as javax.persistence.* is renamed to jakarta.persistence.*