# Maven, Spring-boot - The import javax.validation can not be resolved

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have the same issue as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327697/spring-boot-javax-import-statements-not-working-correctly) (sorry am not yet able to comment) but the  suggested dependency in the accepted answer did not help me (i have it already).

**What caused the problem for me :**
I had the project working fine on a computer then i decided to move to another computer which is more convenient for coding. In the new computer, i installed the exact same environnement (Jdk1.8, Eclipse for JEE latest version) then i imported the project as existing maven project but i can not build it due to the mentionned error.

What can i do to import it ?

I tried many solutions like running maven clean, maven update, deleting old target folder...etc.

Comment: Should add code to this question, we won't be able to help you without code.

Comment: Maven may have corrupted a jar file when it downloaded it. Try clearing out Maven’s cache and rebuilding your application.

Comment: Thank you @Andy, clearing Maven'cache solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

For those who may wonder : Clearing Maven'c cache solved the problem (deleting .m2\repository in current user directory for Windows) as @Andy Wilkinson said in comment.